# What does the notation "$\sim$" mean as in "proportional to/in the same order of"?

Tags: analysis, notation

I have a book where they define the notation $\sim$ in $a \sim b$ as in "$a$ proportional to $b$" or "$a$ is in the same order of b" but what does this really mean? I read somewhere that it means asymptotically equal to but I'm not sure if it's equivalent to this context. Can anyone provide intuition for this or why and when we should use this notation as compared to $\simeq$?

Comment: When would you use $\simeq$ in analysis? I only know it in topological context (homotopy), or sometimes in algebra (isomorphism, but there is also $\cong$).

Comment: @red_trumpet, correct me if i'm wrong, $\simeq$ shows asymptotic equality. When a variable approaches a certain value as, say $n$ increases, or something similar.

Comment: It has many different meanings. In an algebraic context, $a\sim b$ means that $a$ and $b$ are in one equivalence class. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3886438/show-that-sim-is-an-equivalence-relation), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456209/equivalence-relation) are tow out of many examples.

Comment: I would use $\propto$ for *proportional to* but that is not the same as *of the same order as*

Comment: In Probability Theory $X \sim F$ means $X$ has the distribution  $F$.

Comment: If you scroll down to Definition 4 [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2022/05/10/partially-specified-mathematical-objects-ambient-parameters-and-asymptotic-notation/), $a \sim b$ is defined as $(a = O(b) \text{ and } b = O(a))$. In other words, there exist absolute constants $C, D > 0$ such that $a \leq Cb$ and $b \leq Da$, where $a, b$ presumably depend on some ambient parameters while $C, D$ do not.